# Insert into postgres using slick in a non blocking way

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick, slick-3.0

```
class Employee(tag: Tag) extends Table[table_types.user](tag,  "EMPLOYEE") {

  def employeeID = column[Int]("EMPLOYEE_ID")
  def empName = column[String]("NAME")
  def startDate = column[String]("START_DATE")

  def * = (employeeID, empName, startDate)
}
object employeeHandle {

    def insert(emp:Employee):Future[Any] = {
      val dao = new SlickPostgresDAO
      val db = dao.db
      val insertdb = DBIO.seq(employee += (emp))
      db.run(insertdb)
  }
}
```

Insert into database a million employee records

```
object Hello extends App {
    val employees = List[*1 million employee list*]
    for(employee<-employees) {
       employeeHandle.insert(employee)
       *Code to connect to rest api to confirm entry*
    }
}
```

However when I run the above code I soon run out of connections to Postgres. How can I do it in parallel (in a non blocking way) but at the same time ensure I don't run out of connections to postgres.

Comment: Have you considered managing your parallelism using Akka Streams? If so, you might be able to use this: https://github.com/MfgLabs/akka-stream-extensions#postgres-extension

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to do it in parallel; I don't see how it can solve it. Instead you could simply create connection before you start that loop and pass it to `employeeHandle.insert(db, employee)`.

Something like (I don't know scala):

```
object Hello extends App {
    val dao = new SlickPostgresDAO
    val db = dao.db
    val employees = List[*1 million employee list*]
    for(employee<-employees) {
       employeeHandle.insert(db, employee)
       *Code to connect to rest api to confirm entry*
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost all examples of slick insert I have come across uses blocking to fullfil the results. It would be nice to have one that doesn't.

My take on it:

```
object Hello extends App {
    val employees = List[*1 million employee list*]
    val groupedList = employees.grouped(10).toList
    insertTests()
    def insertTests(l: List[List[Employee]] = groupedList): Unit = {
      val ins = l.head
      val futures = ins.map { no => employeeHandle.insert(employee)}
      val seq = Future.sequence(futures)
      Await.result(seq, Duration.Inf)
      if(l.nonEmpty) insertTests(l.tail)
    }
}
```

Also the connection parameter in insert handle should be outside

```
object employeeHandle {
      val dao = new SlickPostgresDAO
      val db = dao.db
    def insert(emp:Employee):Future[Any] = {
      val insertdb = DBIO.seq(employee += (emp))
      db.run(insertdb)
  }
}
```